# Android Admob Not enough space to show ad

Tags: android, admob, android-linearlayout, space, android-xml

Used the code provided in [admob site](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals)

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_img"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/atozlayout"
     >
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="55dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp"  

    >

</GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But the logcat shows 
E/Ads(4244): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <800, 0>

Seems like the layout is creating issue. Please suggest way to fix. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your grid is taking up all the space with **layout_height="fill_parent"**.

You can use **layout_weight="1"** and **layout_height="0dp"** to tell the grid to take up all the remaining space after other views are shown.

Also are you adding the AdView programmatically? You can place it in the xml below the GridView.

Ex:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_img"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/atozlayout"
     >
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="55dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp">

</GridView>
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Make sure you replace adUnitId with your value.

Comment: yes, i am placing adview programatically... can u please post snippet to place using xml?

Comment: Thanks a lot This was really nice! b/w can u please explain the requirement of ds:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID". Do we need to remove them before deploying the app? Many Thanks

Comment: Yes. You can read about testing here.  https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/best-practices#testmode

Comment: I'm looking for a perfect solution where if user didn't connect to internet or the Ad didn't loaded successful it will not occupied the screen and leave an empty banner there. Looks like the layout_height="wrap_content" not work as expected though.

Comment: @yancyn When that happens you should manually hide the ad view.

Answer (score 2):

Your gridView is greedy.  Its eats all available space on the screen.  The solution is to switch the top level layout to a Relative layout, and add android:layout_above"@+id/adview" to the GridView and android:layout_alignParentBottom=true  to the ad view.  This will force the gridview to leave room beneath it for the ad.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android tab on the page which you linked, you need a `<com.google.ads.AdView>` view in your layout which seems to be missing from your original post.